# How to assign value to String from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

I have a project in Spring Boot and I have defined some third party API key value pair in application.properties.

But I'm unable to assign that value to my String.

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api/v1
server.use-forward-headers=true
Postmark.Apikey=3b2************************
```

**Email.class**

```
@Component
public class Email {

@Value("${Postmark.Apikey}")
private String TEST_API_KEY;
    public void SendMail(String TO, String SUBJECT, String HTMLBODY) {

        System.out.println("TEST_API_KEY "+TEST_API_KEY);

        String FROM = "amit@pharmerz.in";
        PostmarkMailSender mailSender = new PostmarkMailSender(TEST_API_KEY);

        PostmarkMessage m = new PostmarkMessage();
        m.setFrom(FROM);
        m.setTo(TO);
        m.setSubject(SUBJECT);
        m.setHtmlBody(HTMLBODY);
        //m.setText(HTMLBODY);
        // m.setTag("test-utf8");
        mailSender.send(m);
    }

}
```

But when I try to print TEST_API_KEY it gives me **null**.

Comment: Try accessing the other properties in your Email class and let us know the values are coming or not?

Comment: How are you accessing the instance of class Email? You shouldn't instantiate it yourself, but access it via `@Autowired` instead. And don't try to access these values in the constructor of the class, as spring might not be able to give you thit data that early.